# Numbered lists that share numbering across sections

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

In Asciidoctor, is it possible to have multiple numbered lists, split across different sections, that all share numbering (perhaps by setting `[start={counter:list-counter}]`). Something like this:

```
== Section A

. item 1
. item 2

== Section B

[start={list-counter}]
. item 3
. item 4

== Section C

[start={list-counter}]
. item 5
. item 6
```

which should render as this:

```
Section A
1. item 1
2. item 2

Section B
3. item 3
4. item 4

Section C
5. item 5
6. item 6
```

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to have a variable that counts the number of previous list items. Or is there?

I could hack this by placing a `[.invisible]#{counter:list-counter}#` on every list item, but hopefully there is a better way.

Comment: Your hack does seem like the only way without writing an extension that would maintain its own list item counter.

Comment: The Jamal extension, which I wrote has a Snippet module and it has a counter macro in it. WIth that you can do exactly what BallpointBen was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing a list over multiple section is not a standard task, I think the clean way to go is definitely with a [counter](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/counters/).

Instead of an ordered list you could instead use a [Description list](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/lists/description/), it does not look the same but brings some flexibility and the main idea is there:

```
== Section A

{counter:list-counter}):: item 1
{counter:list-counter}):: item 2

== Section B

{counter:list-counter}):: item 3
{counter:list-counter}):: item 4

== Section C

{counter:list-counter}):: item 5
{counter:list-counter}):: item 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another hack:

```
= Document

== Section A

. item 1
. item 2
+
[discrete]
== Section B

. item 3
. item 4
+
[discrete]
== Section C

. item 5
. item 6
```

That gets the list items to have the correct item numbers, but the "discrete" headings are indented. You could use some CSS customization (say via [docinfo files](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/docinfo/)) to outdent them.